# What are some ways I can reduce the bulk of a new ruby on rails autogenerated application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to using ruby on rails and I am starting with the default auto-generated ruby on rails application. I am afraid to enter my first code review with too many files being pushed to github. Are there any best practices for reducing the bulk, size, or amount of files in a default ruby on rails project without losing functionality? Does it heavily depend on the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your concerns are not so much about the bulk of the code but the bulk of the *review*. But, there is no need to review that code, unless the reviewer does not trust Rails, in which case, he has a [metric sh*t-ton more code](https://github.com/rails/rails) to review anyway.

What you *should* do is:

- *Do not* change any of the auto-generated files. Just run the generator and directly commit.
- *Clearly document* the exact version and command line arguments of the generator in your commit message.

That way, instead of reviewing all the code you committed, the reviewer can instead *run the generator himself* on his local machine and *compare the output to your commit*. Now, the task has become much simpler, because the reviewer only needs to review

- the *difference* between the two (which should be zero) and
- the *command line arguments* to the generator (which is just a couple of characters).

In other words, this shifts the burden of trust from yourself to the Rails maintainers, and hopefully, the reviewer trusts them.

Note: this is the same procedure you would follow when you do a mass reformatting of the entire codebase, or when you perform complex refactorings with the help of automated tools. You document the *tool* and then the reviewer can review *how you invoke the tool* instead of reviewing the commit.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be concerned about too many files in your first push to GitHub, as anyone using rails would know exactly what the massive framework looks like.

1. you could do the first push and commit with only the auto-generated code, so all the following commits will be solely about your code;
2. you could delete javascript files, helpers, tests (!) that might be automatically scaffolded if you are planning to leave them empty;